# How to use fminunc with summation in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the following function with fminunc:

```
Σ((x(i)-1).^2) for i = 1 to 20
```

My code is below:

```
fun4 =  @(x) sum((x(i)-1).^2, i, 1, 20)
[x,fval,exitflag,output]= fminunc(fun4,[1,1])
```

And, it gives the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> sym.sym>notimplemented at 2514
>
> Function 'subsindex' is not implemented for MuPAD symbolic objects.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: you could use `fun4 = @(x) sum((x(1:20)-1).^2)`, your current syntax looks odd to me

Comment: I do not get the same error message. Can you `clear` your workspace before running this code and check the error message?

Comment: @Wolfie It gives this error: ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions. Error in ==> @(x)sum((x(1:20)-1).^2)

Comment: @m7913d I am sure about my error. I am using R2009b. Is it about the version of my MATLAB?

Comment: Can you put your provided code in a separate script file (`.m`) and call `clear` on top of it? Does it give you the same error message? If not, please provide a [MCVE]. I don't think it is a version problem.

Comment: If my suggestion is giving an "index exceeds matrix dimensions" error then the `x` you are passing into `fun4` has fewer than 20 elements in it. That's an issue with your `x` not the function...

Comment: @Wolfie It worked, thanks a lot... :)

Comment: No problem, I've added an answer which contains more detail and the solution, feel free to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [`sum` documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) for details about how to use it to sum over a vector.

In your case, if you have a vector `x` of *at least 20 elements*, you can get the subvector of "`x(i)` for `i` in the range 1 to 20" by `x(1:20)`.

You can subtract scalars from a vector just by using the standard subtract sign, but to then square all of the elements individually you should use an "element-wise" operator (having a dot before the operator, like `.^`). As it happens, you were already doing this anyway.

The 2nd, 3rd and 4th arguments you were passing to `sum` are causing an error, because `sum` doesn't expect the arguments you are passing to it. For further details on the inputs it *does* expect see the linked docs.

---

All of this means your function can be simplified:

```
fun4 = @(x) sum((x(1:20)-1).^2);
```